# Patching over logger when running unittests

Tags: python-3.x, logging, python-unittest

In the main.py:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("Mylogger")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.FileHandler(/my/path/ + "Mylogger.log")
logger.addHandler(handler)


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn

    def main(self):
    ....
```

In the test_main.py:

```
class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.my_class = MyClass:("/my/test/path/")

    def test_init(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.my_class.fn, "/my/test/path/")
```

I recently added the logger to the module. However I get the following traceback now:

```
 File "/my/project/src/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    handler = logging.FileHandler(/my/path/ + "MyLogger.log")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/my/path/Mylogger.log'
```

I'd like to somehow to patch over the logger when called via the unnittests. What is the moost pythonic way to patch over this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (it was creating the .log when executed, regardless of content):

```
handler = logging.FileHandler(/my/path/ + "Mylogger.log", delay=True)
```